# HTML, making a button submit data to another url?

Tags: html

The following is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"> Make a new account </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> Note: Just in case someone is wondering, it is utilizing the bootstrap
>   library.

I have the form and it POSTs to login.php but I want the button `Make a new account` post the **same** data to register.php.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set `action` attribute of your `form` tag to the URL of the page to send the data to.

Comment: i thought, and actually do, the same for all languages i've worked with, except for MS Razor pages, where it seems it doesn't work, since it posts to the same url from the browser

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1 at least, I'm able to set the asp-page and asp-route-... attributes on the input tag used for submission. You need to create a shell cshtml file so that url generation works. The end result is a formaction attribute that routes the form to the correct Razor page POST handler.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

In HTML add an onclick event handler for `Make a new account` button:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="myform">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:register()"> Make a new account </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

In JavaScript:

```
function register() {
    this.action = 'register.php';
    return true;
}
```

If this does not work, you may try:

```
function register() {
    var frm = document.getElementById("myform");
    frm.action = 'register.php';
    return true;
}
```

One or both of the above mentioned solution should work for you. Prefer the first approach as it is cleaner.

Please take this as a starting point not a copy-paste solution and follow the best practices for development.

Comment: Why use JS when there is an attribute in HTML that exist exactly for that?

Comment: @ItayGal, there are two submit buttons on the form. The asker wants to submit the same form to two different URLs depending on the button clicked by the user. So, **we are using the default value for action attribute for one button** and **updating action attribute on click of the second button**.

Answer (score 8):

> I have the form and it POSTs to login.php but I want the button Make a new account post the same data to register.php.
>
> Is that possible?

In HTML5 it is, using the [formaction](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formaction) attribute on the submit button.

But browser support is probably not so good yet. Could be resolved using a Polyfil that attaches click handlers to such buttons automatically and changes the `action` attribute of the form dynamically, though.

Comment: Browser support is here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp
TLDR: if it's a general web site you probably can't use, but if you have a "Web Interface" to an internal or restricted users where you have more power to require recent browsers, this is the best solution.

Comment: @PauloSchreiner you're going to get yourself killed for using w3schools as a reference, just warning you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="register.php">
```

Comment: Thats not what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another **submit** button with **formaction** attribute.

```
 <form action="/submit">

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      
      <input type="submit" value="Go Elsewhere" formaction="/elsewhere">
      
 </form>
```

For more details, you can visit [this](https://css-tricks.com/separate-form-submit-buttons-go-different-urls/) url.